# How to convert my Wordpress website to flutter application?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, flutter, mobile-application, wordpress-rest-api

I am a college student and during my intern my client gave me this project to convert his wordpress website into a mobile application while including existing features as well as some new features. The website is news website. I am also provided with wordpress admin panel credentials.
However, I am having hardtime fetching all data of website in json form. I tried using the wordpress api url: "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" as well as 
"https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?perpage=100" and
"https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[limit]=100"
but none of them provided with whole data, it only rendered 10 latest news posts.
I am looking to get whole access to the website data myself. Is there any possible way for that? I want comments from the users on that news post, number of shares, likes, the related news section below post, everything. 
Do I have to ask for the organization's main api or is there any other way? I am fluent in flutter and node js.

Answer (score 2):

### Flutter WordPress

Flutter WordPress is a library that allows for easy communication between a Flutter app and the WordPress backend. It uses WordPress REST API v2 for this interaction.

[image]

If your app is going to make use of authentication or other admin level APIs then the developer recommends you use these two authenthentication wordpress plugins:

1. [Application Passwords](https://wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords/)
2. [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) (recommended)

### How to use Flutter WordPress

1.Go to your pubspec.yaml then add the following as a dependency:

```
flutter_wordpress: ^0.1.4
```

You can check for the latest version [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_wordpress).

2.Import it in your code:

```
import 'package:flutter_wordpress/flutter_wordpress.dart' as wp;
```

3.You instantiate WordPress:

```
wp.WordPress wordPress;

// adminName and adminKey is needed only for admin level APIs
wordPress = wp.WordPress(
baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
authenticator: wp.WordPressAuthenticator.JWT,
adminName: '',
adminKey: '',
);
```

4.You then authenticate the user:

```
Future<wp.User> response = wordPress.authenticateUser(
username: 'ChiefEditor',
password: 'chiefeditor@123',
);

response.then((user) {
createPost(user);
}).catchError((err) {
print('Failed to fetch user: $err');
});
```

5.Here's how you can fetch wordpress posts and show them in your flutter app:

```
 Future<List<wp.Post>> posts = wordPress.fetchPosts(
 params: wp.ParamsPostList(
 context: wp.WordPressContext.view,
 pageNum: 1,
 perPage: 20,
 order: wp.Order.desc,
 orderBy: wp.PostsOrderBy.date,
 ),
 fetchAuthor: true,
 fetchFeaturedMedia: true,
 fetchComments: true,
 );
```

6.And here's how you can fetch users:

```
Future<List<wp.User>> users = wordPress.fetchUsers(
params: wp.ParamsUserList(
context: wp.WordPressContext.view,
pageNum: 1,
perPage: 30,
order: wp.Order.asc,
orderBy: wp.UsersOrderBy.name,
role: wp.UserRole.subscriber,
),
);
```

7.And here's how to fetch comments:

```
 Future<List<wp.Comment>> comments = wordPress.fetchComments(
 params: wp.ParamsCommentList(
 context: wp.WordPressContext.view,
 pageNum: 1,
 perPage: 30,
 includePostIDs: [1],
 ),
 );
```

8.Then creating a wordpress post via flutter is easy:

```
  void createPost(wp.User user) {
  final post = wordPress.createPost(
  post: new wp.Post(
  title: 'First post as a Chief Editor',
  content: 'Blah! blah! blah!',
  excerpt: 'Discussion about blah!',
  author: user.id,
  commentStatus: wp.PostCommentStatus.open,
  pingStatus: wp.PostPingStatus.closed,
  status: wp.PostPageStatus.publish,
  format: wp.PostFormat.standard,
  sticky: true,
),
);

post.then((p) {
print('Post created successfully with ID: ${p.id}');
postComment(user, p);
}).catchError((err) {
print('Failed to create post: $err');
});
}
```

Then to post a comment:

```
void postComment(wp.User user, wp.Post post) {
final comment = wordPress.createComment(
 comment: new wp.Comment(
  author: user.id,
  post: post.id,
  content: "First!",
  parent: 0,
),
);

comment.then((c) {
print('Comment successfully posted with ID: ${c.id}');
}).catchError((err) {
print('Failed to comment: $err');
});
}
```

Download full example [here](https://github.com/dreamsoftin/flutter_wordpress/archive/master.zip).

Comment: This does not work with the latest Flutter version, anymore.